# MigraDoc / PdfSharpCore - Requesting a fontface "New"

Tags: .net-core, migradoc, pdfsharpcore

```
table.Rows[0].Cells[4].AddParagraph("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZ")
   .Format.Font.ApplyFont(new Font("barcode", 36));
...

var documentRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(_document);
documentRenderer.PrepareDocument(); //<--- crash here
```

It comes through my custom font resolver `ResolveTypeface("barcode", false, false)` and `GetFont("barcode.ttf")` as expected.

It then comes through with `ResolveTypeface("New", false, false)`.  I don't know where "New" is coming from.

If I change new Font("barcode", 36) to new Font("Arial", 36) all is well and it never askes for a fontface of "New".  I've tried another font, just in case something was messed up there.  I've looked through the MigraDoc / PdfSharpCore source but see no reference to a hardcoded "New" string.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that MigraDoc to PDF conversion looks up the FontFamily from the font that it used to resolve and then uses *that* font family (not the original one) when generating the PDF.

This means 2 things:

- You better use the *exact* font family name that is in the font when resolving it.
- You font needs to be correct / not corrupted.  Somewhere it's grabbing "New" from the font I was using.